# Creating a unit file for services in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, celery, systemd

Below is the code from my docker-compose.yml file

```
 version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:9.5'
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass XXXXXXXXXXXXX
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" --reload "whs.app:create_app()"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/whs'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

  celery:
    build:
    command: celery worker -B -l info -A whs.blueprints.contact.tasks   
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/whs'

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
```

Code from celery.service unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Run %p
Requires=docker.service redis.service
After=docker.service redis.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill %p
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f %p
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %p \
  --network whs \
  -v /var/lib/%p/data:/data %p:4.0.2
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %p

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

1. Not sure where to include this **command: celery worker -B -l info -A whs.blueprints.contact.tasks** ,**volumes:** in the unit file
2. The above unit file runs fine but celery is not getting connected to redis as it's not able to update the default BROKER_URL ENVIRONMENT variable. Below is where it's trying to connect

> -------------- celery@2435cb584127 v4.0.2 (latentcall)
>
> ```
> ---- **** -----                                                                                    
> --- * ***  * -- Linux-4.19.0-9-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-8.8 2020-07-17 19:21:16                    
> -- * - **** ---                                                                                    
> - ** ---------- [config]                                                                           
> - ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x7f06bd860ba8 (.default.Loader)                           
> - ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@rabbit:5672//                                      
> - ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://                                                        
> - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)                                                        
> -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)                    
> --- ***** -----                                                                                    
>  -------------- [queues]                                                                           
>                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
> ```

Below code in my app.py which should update the celery config

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                    include=CELERY_TASK_LIST)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

The Application is working fine when running on my local system using **docker-compose up**. Only difference with the remote server being using systemd unit files for these services.

It would be a great assistance if any one could. Thanks..